# Wp Redirect - Call to undefined Function - New plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a new plugin. I have a form which sends a post to a different page. Once the action is complete. I want the page to redirect back to the form that called the script.

I have tried wp_redirect function. But I get an error saying call to undefined function.

Could anyone tell me. Which files are to be included in the action file with the whole path. Or any other method. So that I get this working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which page does the form go to? Do you have it going to a PHP file?

Comment: @ Nathan Dawson: Yes it goes to a php file, I have created in the new plugins folder. Also it's going to that file but it does not redirect since the function is not getting defined. I need a way to define the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a standard form handler that you can use in these situations, `wp-admin/admin-post.php`.

When setting up the from for your plugin, ensure that you use the following HTML -

```
<form action="admin-post.php" method="post"> // Add a name/ID if you wish, but it's not required

    <?php wp_nonce_field('nonce-to-check'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_my-plugin" />

    /** Output your plugin page here */

</form>
```

Now you can add an action so that when the user clicks submit, `admin-post.php` will call that action in a safe way (I.e. including all of the WP goodness, including `wp_redirect`.

```
add_action('admin_post_save_my-plugin', array(&$this, 'on_save_changes'));
```

I recommend using Class's when creating plugins, as it allows for easier structuring.

## Update

You mentioned that you are redirecting from the front end. This is still possible using `admin-post.php` (ignore my comment where I said it was not, I was wrong), you just have to reference `wp-admin\admin-post.php` instead and make use of the `nopriv` action.

On the front end you can include your form like this -

```
$example_plugin = new Example_Plugin();
$example_plugin->output_form();
```

Here is an updated full example of a plugin that will add a button to your Settings menu to demonstrate proper WP redirection from the admin area.

**Note** - some functions that are available when you are in the admin area are not available on the front end, thus necessitating different ways of outputting/working. To this end I've added the `$is_admin` property.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Example Plugin
 * Description: An example plugin to show how they work, and how simple they are to set up.
 * Author: David Gard
 * Version: 2.0.1
 */
 
$example_plugin = new Example_Plugin();
class Example_Plugin{

    private $user_logged_in;
    private $is_admin;
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct(){
    
        $this->user_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();    // Whether or not a user is logged in
        $this->is_admin = is_admin();                   // Whether or not the user is in the admin area
        
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'on_admin_menu'));
        add_action('admin_post_save_my-plugin', array(&$this, 'on_save_changes'));
        add_action('admin_post_nopriv_save_my-plugin', array(&$this, 'on_save_changes'));
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Add a button the the Settings menu
     */
    function on_admin_menu(){
    
        $this->pagehook = add_submenu_page('options-general.php', __('Example Plugin'), __('Example Plugin'), 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', array(&$this, 'on_show_page'));
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Action any changes and save them if required (admin area)
     */
    function on_save_changes(){

        /** Checks user permisisons */
        if($this->user_logged_in && !current_user_can('manage_options')) :
            $warning = new Invalid_Action('permission');
            wp_die($warning, 'Cheatin&#8217; uh?', array('back_link' => true));
        endif;
        
        /** Validate the securiy nonce (I.e. make sure the user is coming here from a valid location) */
        check_admin_referer('nonce-to-check'); // The should match the value of 'wp_nonce_field()'
        
        /** Set a default status */
        $status = 99;
        
        /** Do your stuff here and then set the necessary status...*/
        $status = 1;
        
        /** Set the correct status (so that the correct splash message is shown */
        $_POST['_wp_http_referer'] = add_query_arg('status', $status, $_POST['_wp_http_referer']);
        
        /** Redirect the user back to where they came from */
        wp_redirect($_POST['_wp_http_referer']);

    }
    
    /**
     * Render the page
     */
    function on_show_page(){
?>
        <div id="example-plugin-id" class="wrap">
        
            <h2>Example Plugin</h2>
            <?php $this->splash_message() ?>
            <?php $this->output_form(); ?>
            
        </div>
<?php
    }
    
    /**
     * Out put the user form
     */
    function output_form(){
        
        $action = ($this->is_admin) ? 'admin-post.php' : 'wp-admin/admin-post.php';
?>
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('nonce-to-check'); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_my-plugin" />
               
            <div id="example-plugin-id-metabox" class="metabox-holder">
                <p>This is a basic example plugin.</p>
                <p>Click the button below to see how redirection works (it uses the 'on_save_changes()' function)</p>
                <?php
                if($this->is_admin) :
                    submit_button(__('Test me out'));
                else :
                    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>';
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            
        </form>
<?php
    }
    
    /**
     * Write a custom message at the top of an admin options page (if necessary)
     */
    private function splash_message(){
    
        /** Check that there is a status for a splash message to be displayed */
        if(!$_REQUEST['status']) :
            return false;
        endif;
        
        /** Work out the class of the splash message */
        $message_classes[1] = 'updated';
        $message_classes[99] = 'error';
        $message_class = $message_classes[$_REQUEST['status']];
        
        $this->set_splash_messages();
        $message = $this->messages_splash[$_REQUEST['status']];
            
        /** Display the message splash */
        echo '<div id="message" class="'.$message_class.' below-h2">';
        echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Set the splash messages available for this plugin
     */
    private function set_splash_messages(){
    
        $this->messages_splash = array(
            0  => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
            1  => __('This test works just fine.'),
            99 => __('An unknown error occured, please try again.')
        );
        
    }
    
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.. It is working without issues.. How would you create a form on the front end the? Since we make use of admin.php

Comment: I have several forms and to action them I basically copied `admin-post.php` and I direct my forms to that page (as `admin-post.php` is not accessible from the front end). You can then simply add another `action` to the `__construct()` function create a matching function within to plugin, helping further to keep it self-contained.

Comment: So the action will be admin-post.php for these pages too? Only we will be writing new functions. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Not quite. From the front end, when there is no user logged in, you have no access to `admin-post.php`. Therefore you should copy it to a file within your theme that is accessible and remove any unnecessary lines (it's a tiny file). I'll update the answer shortly to demonstrate the technique more succinctly.